# Entity Framework Select top row from each type based on subobject value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am using EF6 Code First approach. I have a the following related tables Events, Markets, MarketTypes with these models

```
  public class Event
  {
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public List<Market> Markets { get; set; } = new List<Market>();
  }

  public class Market
  {
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public Guid EventID { get; set; }
    public Event Event { get; set; }
    public Guid TypeID { get; set; }
    public MarketType Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime InitiateDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdateDateTime { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
  }

  public class MarketType
  {
    public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
  }
```

Each event have many markets and each market has one type. I am using the following statement to get list of events.

```
List<Event> events = new List<Event>();   
var startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, DateTime.UtcNow.Day);   
var endDate = startDate.AddHours(24);
events = _context.Events
        .Include(e => e.Markets)
        .Include(e => e.Markets.Select(i => i.Type))
        .Where(e => e.DateTime >= startDate)
        .Where(e => e.DateTime < endDate)
        .OrderBy(e => e.DateTime)
        .ToList();
```

Is it possible to update the above query in order to retrieve one market row of each type which is the last updated one (having largest 'LastUpdateDateTime' value). I am currently doing this through an ugly manual method.

Answer (score 0):

if your want last updated values, I use in this case OrderByDescending, that will be sort a list with last .

like this:

```
_context.Events
.Inlcude(e=>e.Markets)
.Include(e=>e.Markets.Select(I=>I.Type))
.Where(e=>e.DateTime>= startDate && e.DateTime<endDate)
.OrderBy(e.DateTime)
.OrderByDescending(e.LastUpdateDateTime )
.ToList();
```

you can't use `ThenbBy` linq cmd because `OrderBy` is for ascending and it is in conflict with `OrderByDescending`.
with this you have a list. 
After you need the cmd First() or FirstOrDefault() to get only the largest one.
I am not sure but if you use cmd FirstOrDefault() instead of where cmd it could be work.
is it good for you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However you assumed that 'LastUpdateDateTime' is a field of 'Events' table. But it is a field of related table 'Market'.

Comment: you're right, and with this `.OrderByDescending(e.Markets.LastUpdateDateTime )`?